# Running named data macros from a linked table

Tags: ms-access

I recently succesfully split an access database. Everything seems to be functioning correctly apart from calling named data macros from a linked table. When attempting to call it through any front-end interface I get:

```
The data macro <linked table>.<macro name> could not be found.
```

I am calling these named data macros through a button on a (front-end) form that uses its own macro to run the "RunDataMacro" command.

Before the database was split, selecting "RunDataMacro" provided me with a drop down list of all the named data macros currently attached to my tables. Now if I try it (with all my tables linked instead of being local) the drop down list is empty.

I have struggled to find similar problems online which leads me to believe it may be due to a small mistake, but I can't be sure. Nothing I have read leads me to believe that named data macros shouldn't work in this case.

Any idea on where I might be going wrong would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Link Tables. Data macros are not supported on link tables; however, you can associate logic on a backend ACCDB database for typical front-end/back-end applications.

[Source](http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-access/archive/2009/08/13/access-2010-data-macros-similar-to-triggers.aspx)

Personally, I can't stand macros. I find them too limiting, a pain to debug, and you have to look all over the place to find the various macros. I realize it's interface makes it easy to build, but I would recommend learning VBA (Visual Basic for Applications). You'll find a TON of examples on the web to help you with almost any problem. Plus you'll find more of us on here to help with future issues you may have when coding VBA.

Good luck

Comment: Ahh that's unfortunate.. thanks though, Tom. The only reason I'm not using VBA is because the task is so simple. I just wanted to add a record to a table, so I made added "AddRecord" data macros to each table. They just passed parameters through to a new record. Is there a standardized way of doing this without data macros that I'm missing? Or should I just resort to using VBA?

Comment: At what point are you adding a record? Are you using a form to input the data?

Comment: Just to confirm, I did in fact end up using VBA to insert the record, but out of curiosity I would still like to know any other ways I could have done it without delving into VBA. I have a form displaying a subform, and fields outside that subform. On click of a certain button I wanted to add whatever was in those fields to the source of the subform. Incredibly trivial in VBA, I know, but it's also such a simple task, I almost expect there to already be an inbuilt way of doing it.

Comment: Glad you got it working. Other ways would probably include a macro (a regular one, not a data one). But as I said, I really do not like them, and would personally never recommend them.